# how to create snake body using arraylist in snake game

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi, I'm developing a snake game. To create the snake I'm using `ArrayList`. While moving the snake I'm getting the following error: "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3, Size: 3". Below is my program. In `Snake.update()` method I have problem.

Game.java:

```
 import javax.swing.JFrame;

 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
   public class Game extends JFrame {
  public Game(){
    add(new GamePanel());
    setTitle("Game Test3");
    setVisible(true);
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Game();
  }
}
```

GamePanel.java:

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.Image;
    import java.awt.RenderingHints;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable, KeyListener {
public static int width = 300;
public static int height = 400;
private Thread thread;
private Image image;
private Graphics2D g;

private Food food;
private Snake snake;

public GamePanel() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    setFocusable(true);
}

public void addNotify() {
    super.addNotify();
    if (thread == null) {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }
    addKeyListener(this);
}

public void run() {
    image = createImage(width, height);
    g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
    RenderingHints reneringHints = new RenderingHints(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g.setRenderingHints(reneringHints);

    food = new Food();
    snake = new Snake();
    while (true) {
        gameRender();
        gameUpdate();
        gameDraw();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void gameDraw() {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) getGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    g2.dispose();
}

private void gameRender() {
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

    // food drawing
    food.draw(g);
    // snake drawing
    snake.draw(g);
}

private void gameUpdate() {
    food.update();
    snake.update();
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
          snake.setLeft(true);
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        snake.setRight(true);
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        snake.setUp(true);
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        snake.setDown(true);
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
          snake.setLeft(false);
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        snake.setRight(false);
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        snake.setUp(false);
    }
    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        snake.setDown(false);
    }
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}

  }
```

//snake body

```
  import java.awt.Color;
  import java.awt.Graphics2D;
  import java.awt.Rectangle;
  import java.util.ArrayList;

 public class Snake {
private int x;
private int y;
private int r;

int body;
Rectangle rectangle;
ArrayList<Rectangle> rc = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
private boolean left;
private boolean right;
private boolean up;
private boolean down;

public Snake() {
    x = 150;
    y = 150;
    r = 4;
    body = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < body; i++) {
        rc.add(new Rectangle(x - i * r * 3, y, r * 3, r * 3));
    }
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g) {

    for (int i = 0; i < body; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            g.setColor(Color.red);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
        }
        g.fillOval(rc.get(i).x, rc.get(i).y, rc.get(i).width,
                rc.get(i).height);
    }
}

public void update() {
    for (int i = body; i > 0; i--) {
        rc.set(i, rc.get(i - 1));
    }
    if (left) {
        rc.get(0).x -= 1;
        System.out.println("vbnv");
    }
    if (right) {
        rc.get(0).x += 1;
    }
    if (up) {
        rc.get(0).y -= 1;
    }
    if (down) {
        rc.get(0).y += 1;
    }
}

public void setLeft(boolean b) {
    left = b;
}

public void setRight(boolean b) {
    right = b;
}

public void setUp(boolean b) {
    up = b;
}

public void setDown(boolean b) {
    down = b;
}

   }
```

Comment: out of curiousity: when you move do you repaint everything or just remove the tail?

Comment: first, i am not able to create snake. then how can i think about that

Comment: well i was thinking about the underlying data structure. you add at one end (head) and remove at the other (tail) - instead of an arraylist you could use  a queue: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html

Comment: i want to do with only arraylist . i can create with array very easily.

Comment: only thing that would change in creation would be the order - have it your way then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without reading the code I can tell that somewhere you are trying to get non-existent element. Read the message of exception, it tells you that your `ArrayList` consist of three elements (which means that the last element has index of 2) while you try to get the element with index of 3.

**Update**: yes, the problem is here:

```
for (int i = body; i > 0; i--) {
    rc.set(i, rc.get(i - 1));
}
```

`body` equals to 3, and `rc` after the constructor invocation has the size of 3. `set` method replaces already existing element with the specified index (see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)), but element with index of 3 doesn't exist. That's the cause of an exception.

Comment: thanks for reply . i know about the error.i wannt to know  how to create snake and move in proper way using arraylist

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in this loop:

```
for (int i = body; i > 0; i--) {
    rc.set(i, rc.get(i - 1));
}
```

During the first iteration around this loop, you will be calling:

```
rc.set(3, <someValue>);
```

3 is not a valid index in a list of length 3. The largest valid index is 2.

Comment: ok is this possible to give like this for (int i = body; i > 0; i--) {
    rc.add(i, rc.get(i - 1)); 
}

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = body; i > 0; i--)
```

In this `for`, i is assigned with the value of body(which is 3) and it looks like your `ArrayList rc` has only 3 elements in it. Therefore, when you try to access the index 3 using `rc.set(3, something)`, its giving the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Always remember, whether it is `Arrays` or `ArrayList`, the max possible index accessible in them is always `array.length - 1` and `ArrayList.size() - 1`.

Comment: i know this problem. but if i use like body-1 in loop .snake tail is disappear.and .what i am confusing is how to move snake body in proper way